# Suppose $\{v_1, ....,v_m\}\in V$. Prove that $\{v_1, ....,v_m\}^\perp=(\text{span}\{v_1, ....,v_m\})^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I intend to answer this question myself. I am reviewing my copy of Sheldon Axler's excellent "Linear Algebra Done Right", and wrote up a solution for this problem, only to have trouble finding it on the net to verify. It certainly isn't on Math.SE that I could find, and I think it is a subtle enough problem that others looking for it will benefit, so I will post the question and give my answer shortly.

Suppose $\{v_1, ....,v_m\}\in V$, where $V$ is a vector space. Prove that $\{v_1, ....,v_m\}^\perp=(\text{span}\{v_1, ....,v_m\})^\perp$.

Comment: Is the perpindicularity symbol used to denote the set of all vectors (in V) that are perpindicular to all members of {v_1,..,v_m}?

Comment: @Alephnull yep, called the "perp".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the inner product on $V$. First, suppose $v\in(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})^\perp$. Then $\forall w\in\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ we have $\langle v,w\rangle =0$. But since $v_i\in\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\}\;\forall i\in[m]$, this implies that $\langle v,v_i\rangle = 0\;\forall i\in[m]$, hence $v\in\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp$, so we have that $(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})^\perp\subseteq\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp$.

For the reverse inclusion, let $v\in\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp$. Suppose $w\in(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})$. Then, by the definition of the span, there exist scalars $a_1,...,a_m$ such that $w=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_mv_m$. Then, we have $\langle w,v\rangle = \langle a_1v_1+\cdots+a_mv_m, v\rangle$, and by the linearity of the inner product in both slots, we have that this is equal to:

$$a_1\langle v_1,v\rangle+\cdots+a_m\langle v_m,v\rangle,$$
but since $v\in\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp$, we have that $\langle v_i,v\rangle=0\;\forall i\in[m]$, and so $\langle w,v\rangle=0$, showing that $v\in(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})^\perp$, and that $\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp\subseteq(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})^\perp$.

By double inclusion, the claim is proved.

I intentionally was extremely detailed. Comments are welcome.

Comment: For the most part, this is fine (if not overly detailed).  The only error I can see is the first sentence, when you say "let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be an inner product on $V$".  The set $(\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_m\})^\perp$ is the annihilator of $\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ with respect to a certain inner product.  So $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ can't be just any inner product, it has to be the one described in the definitions of $\{v_1,...,v_m\}^\perp$.

Comment: @Aweygan Detail is the only way I get anything done, so forgive me. :) In your personal opinion, does it make more sense to just leave any notion of a specific inner product out entirely (since the one we are using is clear from the context), or add in the bit about it being the specific one?

Comment: The notation used for the inner product should either be clear from context (i.e. it was stated earlier that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard notation for an inner product on a vector space, when there is no possibility for confusion), be defined in the statement of the proposition (i.e. the proposition should begin by stating "Let $V$ be an inner product space, with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$"), or should be stated at the beginning of the proof (i.e. the proof should begin by stating "Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denote the inner product on $V$").

Comment: so, I've just changed "an" to "the". Nice and tidy. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll admit, it is a very small change, but it does make a big difference.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly fine. In fact, while it's a good observation and technically it is incorrect to use something and later on define it (It still is open to debate wheter "after in the sentence" implies "after in time" but OK), I don't think that the issue with the first sentence is a real problem; it is clear that you were having in mind the same inner product through the whole proof, and as this proof is deliberately overdetailed I'd rather regard this as a wording-issue instead of a mathematical flaw.

Comment: I just noticed that what @Aweygan pointed out was the use of the word 'an' instead of the fact that technically as your proof is written you actually use implicitly $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ before you define it. The second part of my last comment (after 'I don't think that the issue...') still applies for this other issue.

Comment: @mathbeing I'll admit my concerns were somewhat pedantic.  But if a proof is overly detailed, all the details should be correct.

Comment: @Aweygan I am not criticizing that "somewhat pedantry" (as my little correction concerning the order of appearance of '$\bot$' and '$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$' would then be super-pedantic), I just wanted to point out that these little concers (both yours and mine) have more to do with mathematical-wording than with reasoning flaws.

Comment: Well, I adjusted it now, regardless. I have achieved what I wanted to achieve, but heck, since we went there, we might as well go all the way.

Answer (score 0):

If $v\in\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}^\bot$ then $v\cdot v_j=0$ for every $1\leq j\leq m$. Pick some $w\in\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$. By definition you can write
$w=\lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_mv_m$ for some scalars $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$, but this means that
$$
v\cdot w=v\cdot(\lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_mv_m)=\lambda_1v\cdot v_1+\cdots+\lambda_mv\cdot v_m=0.
$$
As $w$ was arbitrary we get that $v\in\left(\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}\right)^\bot$. This proves the inclusion $$\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}^\bot\subset\left(\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}\right)^\bot.$$
The other one is trivial because $A\subset B\Rightarrow B^\bot\subset A^\bot$ always holds.

Comment: While this is a fine proof to the stated proposition, the OP didn't ask for a proof.  He/she asked for feedback on his/her proof.

Comment: @Aweygan FWIW, I have no problem with mathbeing posting this proof. Since mine was so intentionally pedantic (for my own benefit/reference), it may be more helpful.

Comment: @Aweygan Did you notice that when I posted this answer the OP hadn't already posted any? It was unclear at the moment if the OP wanted just someone to check his/her answer or if he/she also wanted some alternative proof. I also was tracking this question for the second part so if you want to downvote, be my guest.